# Get an enumerator for the implemented interface from a class array

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have such a function

```
sealed class AssignedTasks : IReadonlyAssignedTasks { ... }

interface IReadonlyAssigningInfo : IEnumerable<IReadonlyAssignedTasks> {}
sealed class AssigningInfo : IReadonlyAssigningInfo {
    private readonly AssignedTasks[] _assignedTasks;
    ...
    public IEnumerator<IReadonlyAssignedTasks> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _assignedTasks.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I have error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.IEnumerator' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: _An explicit conversion exists_ so you can try `(IEnumerator<IReadonlyAssignedTasks>)_assignedTasks.GetEnumerator()`

Comment: Use Linq to make it more readable, and just return this: `return _assignedTasks.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want to return the interface while the array contains the class.

You need to cast the items before returning an enumerator

```
public IEnumerator<IReadonlyAssignedTasks> GetEnumerator()
{
    return _assignedTasks.Cast<IReadonlyAssignedTasks>().GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Or just do `return _assignedTasks.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();`

Answer (score 0):

because _assignedTask is array and _assignedTasks.GetEnumerator() will return non generic version of `IEnumerable`. Try following it would work

```
sealed class AssigningInfo : IReadonlyAssigningInfo {
    private readonly List<AssignedTasks> _assignedTasks;
    ...
    public IEnumerator<IReadonlyAssignedTasks> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _assignedTasks.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Have a look into the MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx).